# Page table number to virtual address

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-address, virtual-memory

In my class where I am supposed to count used and modified pages in the given table and the command only gets the page table number as input from the user.

However, I know how to count used and modified pages, but I will need the virtual address which I don't know how to calculate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Need a lot more information. What tables?

Comment: What language is this in? Do you have a code sample?